# Best way to declare functions on javascript objects

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

When defining javascript objects that behave like classes that have state and functions that manipulate that state is it better to define functions when defining the object like so:

```
function MyNewClass(){
   //State
   this.value = ""
   this.otherValue = ""
   //Functions
   this.someFunction = function(){
      //Some logic here
   }
}
```

Or it it better practice to define functions on the prototype of the object such as:

```
function MyNewClass (){
   //state
   this.value = ""
   this.otherValue = ""
}

MyNewClass.prototype.someFunction = function(){
  //Some logic here
}
```

Are there any advantages to defining object functions on the prototype? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because **functions are objects**, given the described scenario, we have two behavior:

- If you declare the function on the "class" function, every object you
  create then it will have a copy of that function (object), so the
  **memory usage will increase**.
- However, if you add the function to the prototype, the function will
  be shared by all the objects, so there will be a **save of memory**

Answer (score 0):

functions of the  object should be declared using prototype because prototype is a common space that is shared by all the objects created by the same constructor function  and it also saves memory because all objects do not have there own functions created but they all are pointing to one common place.
you can refer it here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBpPfPjxOhc&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTaflXUL0v3TSm86nodn0c_u 
example

```
enter code here
```

//constructor function

```
function gh(){
this.x=1;
}
//now if you create a object 
var p=new gh();
//now i need function show in my object p
function show(){
console.log(x);
}
gh.prototype.show=show();
```

//it will be added all objects automatically (to understand this study scope chain)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference for yourself by running this code:

```
var output = function(s) { document.getElementById("output").innerText += s; }

function MyNewClass() {
   this.foo = function() {
      output("1");
   }
}

MyNewClass.prototype.bar = function(){
      output("2");
};
var a = new MyNewClass();
a.foo();
a.bar();


a.foo = function() { output("3") };
MyNewClass.prototype.bar = function() { output("4"); };

a.foo();
a.bar();

var b = new MyNewClass();
b.foo();
b.bar();
```

The output is: 123414

When you change a function as a member variable, you only change that instance. If you change it in the prototype, it affects all instances.